# Ejecutar una acción onchange en un select2_

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Buen día a todos, estoy intentando aplicar una acción al realizar cambios en un `select2`.
Este es mi Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#t_usos").change(function() {
alert( $(this).val()); });
```

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('usos') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">*Tipo de Uso Solicitado:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <select class="select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Seleccionar Tipo de Uso" name="t_usos[]" id="t_usos[]" style="width: 100%;">
                    @foreach($usos as $uso)
                    <option value="{{$uso->id}}">{{$uso->nombre}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Pero al realizar cambios en el `select2`, es decir al seleccionar otra opción del select, no me muestra el alert que puse de prueba, de hecho en la consola de chrome no aparece nada, no estoy seguro de lo que hace falta. Gracias.

Comment: Estás llamando al id del `select` como `t_usos[]`, debería ser `t_usos` sin los corchetes.

Comment: ya hice el cambio, pero sigue igual. el alert no se activa. que otra opcion puede ser?

Comment: Debería funcionar, mirá este [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79xmpw55/) con lo básico y muestra el alert. Fijate si te tira algún error en consola.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que probablemente el select2 se inicializa despues que la pagina carga, por eso debes utilizar "on" asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#t_usos").on("change", function() {
  alert( $(this).val()); });
```

Comment: Excelente!! `<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select2').select2();
    $('#t_usos').on("change", function(e) { 
   alert($(this).val());
 });
});
</script>` me funcionó de esta forma. Mil gracias por tu ayuda